# Typescript generics - extending generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Long-time C++ guy getting deeper into Typescript.  Here's the basic setup of classes I'm importing from a library:

```
export abstract class A<T> {
    ...
    // Common functionality
}

export class B extends A<B> {
    ...
}

export class C extends A<C> {
    ...
}

export class D extends A<D> {
}
```

So essentially B, C, and D have their own public API, but all share the common API and implementation of A.

Now I'd like to create my own extension X of A with more common functionality, and create BX, CX, and DX that share this new functionality as well.

In C++ you could do something like:

```
<template T>
class X : public T {
    ...
    // Common functionality
};

class BX : public X<B> {
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for this in Typescript.  Doing something like:

```
class X<T> extends T {
}
```

in Typescript gives an error.  Also I'd like to add the constraint that T extends A at some point.

Can someone provide some insight for me?  Thanks in advance!

- Steve

Comment: You really want `X<T>` to extend `T`?  Meaning an `X<string>` is also a `string`?  Or do you want `X<T>` to extend `A<T>`?

Comment: Hi!  I can't change the library definitions of B, C, and D.  But now I want to write a common X class that rests on top of B, C, and D to form BX, CX, and DX.  So essentially if I have an instance of BX, I can access all the public methods of A, B, and X ( for example ).  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: But a constraint I'd like to have is that the template parameter T extends A down the line.   So I can't have something like X<string>.  I could only have something like X<B>, X<C>, or X<D> because B, C, and D all extend A.

Comment: You can have `class X<T extends A<T>>` but you can't extend the generic parameter itself (a class/interface needs to know its property names statically...)  You might need mixins or other factories that return intersections.

Comment: Thanks for your input, jcalz.  In my case I'd ideally want methods of X to also call methods of A.  X is sort of an extension of A, but because B, C, and D are in the middle it makes it difficult.  I'll keep researching, but I appreciate your responses!